# Anybody using Gibraltar debugging tools?

Tags: .net, debugging

Looks like these guys have bought some StackOverflow ad space. I watched the Video Tour on their site and read the blurb.

Is anybody using this app? Is it actually as helpful as they claim, or even just 5% as helpful?

Answer (score 2):

**GREAT NEWS!   -- GIBRALTAR is now FREE! --**

[Screenshots of Loupe Desktop -- the FREE successor to Gibraltar Analyst http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/Images/Desktop_fullsize.png](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/Images/Desktop_fullsize.png)
We've changed the name to [Loupe Desktop](http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/announcements/our-best-log-viewer-is-now-free), but it contains everything you loved about Gibraltar Analyst:

- Great highlighting, filtering and grouping to quickly find root causes
- Shows source code associated with each log messag
- Graph of dozens of useful performance metrics
- Chart custom metrics for performance and usage analysis
- Support for massive log files containing millions of messages
- Organize and manage many thousands of logs
- Wizard to integrate logging with your .NET in seconds
- Packager utility that enables users to submit logs to you

We even added support for online local logging so you can live stream log data from any Loupe-enabled application running on your computer.

Read our blog for more about why [**our best log viewer is now FREE**](http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/announcements/our-best-log-viewer-is-now-free)

Or visit our website to [**learn more about Loupe**](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com) or just [**get the bits now!**](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/Try/)

And if you want even more functionality, Loupe Server can aggregate logs from all your applications on all the computers they run on.  It provides smart notifications, powerful analysis and triage tools and a streamlined workflow to tracking resolution of software issues.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'll have another look.